# Android: duplicate classes errors only when using remote dependency but not local JAR

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've a simple Android application project in Android Studio, where I am including this dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // dependency I care about:
    implementation 'org.typesense:typesense-java:0.0.9-beta9'

    // other android deps    
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'

    // test deps
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}
```

When I build the project, I get lots of errors about duplicate classes. Example:

```
Duplicate class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.ArrayType found in modules jackson-databind-2.14.1 (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1) and typesense-java-0.0.9-beta9 (org.typesense:typesense-java:0.0.9-beta9)
Duplicate class okio.Throttler found in modules okio-jvm-2.8.0 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.8.0) and typesense-java-0.0.9-beta9 (org.typesense:typesense-java:0.0.9-beta9)
```

I'm not using any other library that uses these dependencies so I don't know what is happening.

Now, the interesting thing is that when I actually download the JAR directly from [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/typesense/typesense-java/0.0.9-beta9/) and depend on it as a local JAR, the errors vanish!

```
implementation files('libs/typesense-java-0.0.9-beta9.jar')
```

Also, when I use the dependency in a vanilla Java/gradle project, I don't face any issues. What is going wrong here?

In case it helps, here's the [source](https://github.com/typesense/typesense-java) of the library I'm trying to depend on.

Comment: I notice that the part with "error vanishes" specifies `…-beta9.jar` where the *dependency I care about* just reads `…-beta9`.

Comment: @greybeard When I use the local JAR file directly using path to `.jar`, I don't see those errors. The "dependency I care about" uses the dependency from Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar contains it's own dependencies, so the classes fetched by Gradle's dependency resolution are duplicates of those included in the jar.

You can instruct Gradle not to manage the dependencies :

```
implementation("org.typesense:typesense-java:0.0.9-beta9") {
    exclude group: '*', module: '*'
}
```

The problem will reappear if something (e.g. another library) declares a dependency on one of the included libraries (Jackson, OkHttp, Log4j, ...)

The jar also contains the Kotlin stdlib. You have to avoid pulling it, directly (in a Kotlin project) or indirectly (e.g. using an AndroidX library written in Kotlin)

A much better solution would probably be to have a version that doesn't include the dependencies in the jar.

By the way, I think there is currently no way to use this library in a Kotlin project.

Comment: Are you saying that Gradle will try to fetch the dependencies of `typesense` (from Typesense gradle configuration?). In that case, the correct fix is for the Typesense library to not publish a "fat" jar to maven central, which it currently does?

Comment: I think so, especially including the Kotlin's stdlib seems quite problematic

Answer (score -1):

Basically the issue lies in the dependency. Multiple dependencies are included in this remote dependency.

[image]

If you want to use the remote dependency, you need to exclude the dependencies.